# Broadcom Wi-Fi Drivers won't activate on retina macbook pro

Tags: 14.04, broadcom, macbook-pro

I'm on a rMBP (Macbook Pro) and have the exact same issue as [this post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1waogn/wifi_drivers_work_for_live_usb_but_not_for/) except I'm using 14.04 . It looks like his problem was solved when he connected via ethernet however....I don't have an ethernet port....
Just like him, drivers activated fine when booted from USB, but after installing, no go. I am dual booting OSX with working wi-fi if that makes a difference

Comment: The installer is supposed to support Broadcom wifi with the proprietary `wl` driver and install it correctly. You should report the failure on Launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

Installing network drivers when you do not have a working network connection is a pain. The easiest way to get a working network connection is to either:

- use a USB ethernet adaptor
- use a USB wifi adaptor that is supported (I have successfully used Atheros and ZyDAS adaptors)
- use a a smartphone that has USB tethering (I have successfully used Android tether over wifi)

Probably the last option is the one that most people would use, since most people either have a smartphone or can borrow one.

Comment: well, he won't be able to tether over Wifi since he doesn't have a working Wifi chipset on his laptop :D

Comment: My Wi-Fi works in osx, so would there be some way to grab the driver there, then access it from ubuntu?

Comment: @MrVaykadji He does not need one. If he has a smartphone he can enable USB tethering on the phone, and then the phone will do the wifi, not the laptop. (If you are talking about the phone using the wifi of the laptop, that is known as *"USB reverse tethering"*).

Comment: @user288620 Try [this package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/linux-firmware-nonfree/download), install it with `dpkg -i linux-firmware-nonfree_1.14ubuntu1_all.deb`

Comment: Sweet thanks. I'll have to try it when I get home